# Is it fine to define module version in activation file?

Tags: magento-1.7, configuration, version

Usually we are defining the module version in `app/code/local/Mymodule/Mynamespace/etc/config.xml` file. But if we put the version in `app/etc/modules/Mymodule_Mynamespace.xml` it also works fine. I know this is because when rendering the Magento system it loads and merge all the *.xml files to one huge xml file. But the thing I want to know is it ok to use the version definition in activation config rather than etc/config.xml ? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest to leave it in `config.xml` to keep a consistency in your code. but if, for some reason, you need it in the declaration file (in `etc/modules`) I don't see any harm in putting it there.
Just be careful. If you add the version in both files the value in `config.xml` will override the one in `etc/modules`.